# How do I bundle the C source in a Raku distribution that uses NativeCall?

Tags: raku, software-distribution, nativecall

I'm writing Raku bindings to a C library, but rather than require the users of the Raku code to install the C library on their own, I'd like to bundle the C code as part of the distribution (it's not such a widely distributed library).

I've read about a distribution's [`%?RESOURCES`](https://docs.raku.org/language/variables#%?RESOURCES), and that seems like it would be useful. But I'm hazy on the specifics of how to apply it for this.

Can I bundle the C source code in the distribution, and specify some way for it to get compiled as part of the installation (eg. with `zef`)? Or would I need to bundle precompiled versions of the library, and get the code to choose the right one depending on the platform?

Or is this simply impossible, and I should just give users instructions on how to install the library separately?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's possible, and there exists a module [LibraryMake](https://github.com/retupmoca/P6-LibraryMake) to ease the process.

For an example of a module using it, see [Digest::SHA1::Native](https://github.com/bduggan/p6-digest-sha1-native).